# Como borrar registros por metodo post y usando solo php y mysql, sin javascript

Tags: php, mysqli, php7, crud

Buen dia Estimados, la consulta que tengo es la siguiente, tengo mi tabla con un boton que tiene incluido un href, el cual para borrar un usuario paso el id de la siguiente manera

```
<td><a href="eliminar.php?id_usuario=<?= $usuario['id_usuario'];?>"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></a></td>
```

En la pagina eliminar.php lo levanto de la siguiente manera

```
    <?php require_once("controladores/funciones.php");

if(!empty($_GET)){
$id = $_GET['id_usuario'];
borrarUsuario($id);
echo "Registro Eliminado";
header('refresh:4; url=administrar.php');
}else{
    echo "Error";
}
?>
```

y la funcion borrarUsuario es la siguiente

```
 function borrarUsuario($id){
        $pdo = conexion();
        $sql = "delete from usuarios where id_usuario = :id_usuario ";
        $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $stmt ->bindValue(':id_usuario',$id);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

Esto esta probado y funciona correctamente. La pregunta es, de que manera podria realizar la misma accion pero sin pasar los parámetros mediante el metodo Get y que no sean visibles en la url. Desde ya espero sus comentarios.

Comment: Puedes empezar por mirar el uso de POST sobre GET

Comment: Hola, no entiendo muy bien lo que queres decir con eso.

Comment: Busca sobre envío de datos por POST y eso te llevará a la respuesta

Comment: Es que eso ya lo se, para enviar por Post tendria que crear un form, pero no creo que esa fuera la manera correcta de realizar esto. Gracias igual por el consejo

Comment: Claro es posible mete ese enlace dentro de un form, cambia a post como te digo y queda

Comment: Por que hacerle el feo a  **Javascript** ?? Realizas peticiones asincronas sin que la página recargue, agregas una bonita animación mientras se realiza el proceso de eliminación, te recomiendo que investigues sobre **fetch** no quiero pensar que este proyecto es en la vida real, pero aunque fuera didáctico sería genial empezar a implementar estás tecnologías.

Comment: Hola Nikola, fetch lo estoy usando con pdo, y no es que le haga feo a javascript, se que se complementa muy bien con php pero en este caso particular quiero realizar el crud sin el uso de js. Gracias igual.

Comment: ¿La idea de hacerlo por POST es para incrementar la seguridad? Porque esa parte debe manejarse del lado del servidor, porque cualquier usuario con conocimientos medios puede modificar el formulario.

Comment: Hola Triby, si decidi seguir mandandolo por el metodo Get ya que solo los administradores van a tener acceso a la parte de eliminar un usuario, por lo que no va a ser visible hacia un usuario comun y se va a manejar todo como vos indicas desde el servidor. Agradezco los consejos. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Podés usar un form con un input de tipo hidden:

```
<form method="post" action="eliminar.php">
    <input type="hidden" name="id_usuario" value="<?php echo $usuario['id_usuario'] ?>">
    <button type="submit"><ion-icon name="trash-outline"></ion-icon></button>
</form>
```

Con el método POST.

Comment: Eso y que estás proponiendo el uso de post, deberías aclararle eso

Comment: Lo unico que ingresando como tipo button le cambia el formato al icono, te adjunto la imagen con el href y con el button. https://ibb.co/D9QYmfs
https://ibb.co/jZ67Brv

Comment: Podría usar una clase css https://stackoverflow.com/a/1368286/5150463

Comment: Si, lo estuve probando pero cambia totalmente el formato del icono. Estoy usando bootstrap y la idea seria que el icono funcione como un button pero sin que cambie el formato. Voy a seguir investigando. Gracias igual